# TS1005: ',' expected. try to double map to return an object

Tags: typescript, eslint

so what im trying to achive here is that im trying to do mapping in map on component props that accept only object as it returns, i tried to use foreach but its error because the props said theres no return.

so heres my code

TS1005: ',' expected.

```
  data={!isEmpty(reducedCategoryExpenseData)
                                ? reducedCategoryExpenseData.map(
                                  (dataInside: any) => (
                                    {
                                      dataInside.reducedData.map((dataPrint: any) => ({
                                        x: dataPrint.month,
                                        y: `$${dataPrint.amount}`
                                      }))
                                    }
                                  )
                                )
                                : []
                            }
```

but it gone error on dataInside.(on this dot part)reducedData   sasying TS1005: ',' expected.
any ideas why? please help

Answer (score 0):

```js
                                 (dataInside: any) => (
                                    {
                                      dataInside.reducedData.map((dataPrint: any) => ({
                                        x: dataPrint.month,
                                        y: `$${dataPrint.amount}`
                                      }))
                                    }
                                  )
```

This section is returning an object because of the parentheses, like this:

```js
something.method((param) => ({ prop: value }));
```

Hence the error (it expected an object expression).

Did you mean:

```
(dataInside: any) => dataInside.reducedData.map(...)
```

to *return* the result

Also please don't use `any` with TypeScript. It really defeats the main purpose.